# Left MB Click is setting the origin of the object

Tags: 3d-cursor

I appear to have changed a setting and I can't figure out what the hell I have done...

On clicking LMB the cursor moves BUT it also sets the origin of the object...

Any ideas? I am half way through a project and I cannot seem to reset the behaviour.

Comment: Using latest version

Comment: Have you tried resetting the preferences?

Comment: Yes I have succeeded in resetting preferences but now as a result of not knowing I have to go through and rest ALL preferences - could do with knowing for the future.